# Closing ChartData Window of a Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have code that opens a Word document and goes through the charts, updating the data.

The problem is that I call this macro multiple times in a row. Even though I close the Word application, the chartdata window remains open.

Excel is crashing without telling me why but E think the problem is with the chartdata windows not being closed. Because if I run the macro only one time, it works.

But, how do I close the chartdata window if the chart doesn't support this property?

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdShape As InlineShape
Dim wdChart As Word.Chart

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True

'Opening the document
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("path_here")

'Opening the chartdata window
Set wdShape = wdDoc.InlineShapes(1)
Set wdChart = wdShape.Chart
wdChart.ChartData.Activate

'Changing the data
Range("B2").Value = 120
Range("B3").Value = 155

'Closing the app
wdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges

Set wdShape = Nothing
Set wdChart = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: Not sure about Word, but in PowerPoint and Excel, you can update the charts without opening the chartdata.

Comment: @mooseman I tried in Word but couldn't figure it out. I will look into that one more time. Ty

Comment: You should set to Nothing in the reverse order that you instantiate (Set the objects), with the application the last. And you can try something like wdDoc.Content.Characters(1).Select to deactivate the chart.

Answer (score 1):

This code will change the values in the data without activating the chartdata window.  For some reason the wdChart variable was throwing a constant assignment error, so I changed it to wdCh.

```
Set wdShape = wdDoc.InlineShapes(1)
Set wdCh = wdShape.Chart
With wdCh.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1)
   .Range("B2").Value = 120
   .Range("B3").Value = 155
End With
```

Comment: I did not test it yet, but this will probably resolve the problem. Thank you. But i did another approach. I linked the charts to the excel and used wdDoc.InlineShapes(i).LinkFormat.Update

Comment: Yes.  If the charts are linked then you can do an update link.  Just be sure to break the link if this is a deliverable without the liked data file.